# Express app not found on localhost 8080

Tags: node.js, express

Trying to get a basic Node Express Hello World app running on my localhost, but getting a page not found browser error:

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send("Hello, World!");
});

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.send("Page not found", 404);
});

app.listen(8080);

console.log("Express server started!");
```

When I run the app, there appears to be no errors in the terminal
[image]

However at `http://localhost:8080` I get this error

**`GET http://localhost:8080/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the port to `9000` and now it works :/ not sure why, but at least it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem.  My hosts file was at it's default state, and localhost resolved to 127.0.0.1 as it should, but when I appended a port number to localhost like localhost:8080, it would give me the same ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE message.

So I did some snooping by running `sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep TCP` into the Terminal and saw 'acwebsecagent' (Cisco AnyConnect) listening to a large range of port numbers.  I remember this app being problematic in later versions of OSX and apparently haven't completely removed it so I uninstalled the app by running `sudo /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/websecurity_uninstall.sh` and localhost:8080 resolves correctly now.

Random Internet slowdowns that also occurred after a few days of Internet usage is also no longer a problem and apparently was caused by this.  Two birds with one stone!